# SUM 2 columns in datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have this datatable:

```
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("ČísloDokladuDodavatele", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("Množství", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("NákupníCena", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("PřepočtováJednotka", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("Přepočtovýkoeficient", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("DoporučenáCena", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("KódZboží", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("Ean", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("Název", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("DPH", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("OS1", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("OS2", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("OS3", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("OS4", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("OS5", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("US1", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("US2", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("US3", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("Oddělení", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("MěrnáJednotka", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("Barva", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("Velikost", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("Délka", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("Šířka", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("TypDokladu(PNS)", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("Datum OD", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("Datum DO", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("Značka", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("Sezona", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("Výrobní č.", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("Popis_Rozpis", typeof(string));
    RadkyData.Columns.Add("Sufix EAN", typeof(string));
```

I need SUM column "Množství" and column "NákupníCena", where is the columns: KódZboží,Ean,Velikost are the same in rows.

This is my code:

```
var res = RadkyData.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(r=>new 
                    {
                        c1 = r.Field<string>("ČísloDokladuDodavatele"),
                        c2 = r.Field<string>("Množství"),
                        c3 = r.Field<string>("NákupníCena"),
                        c4 = r.Field<string>("PřepočtováJednotka"),
                        c5 = r.Field<string>("Přepočtovýkoeficient"),
                        c6 = r.Field<string>("DoporučenáCena"),
                        c7 = r.Field<string>("KódZboží"),
                        c8 = r.Field<string>("Ean"),
                        c9 = r.Field<string>("Název"),
                        c10 = r.Field<string>("DPH"),
                        c11 = r.Field<string>("OS1"),
                        c12 = r.Field<string>("OS2"),
                        c13 = r.Field<string>("OS3"),
                        c14 = r.Field<string>("OS4"),
                        c15 = r.Field<string>("OS5"),
                        c16 = r.Field<string>("US1"),
                        c17 = r.Field<string>("US2"),
                        c18 = r.Field<string>("US3"),
                        c19 = r.Field<string>("Oddělení"),
                        c20 = r.Field<string>("MěrnáJednotka"),
                        c21 = r.Field<string>("Barva"),
                        c22 = r.Field<string>("Velikost"),
                        c23 = r.Field<string>("Délka"),
                        c24 = r.Field<string>("Šířka"),
                        c25 = r.Field<string>("TypDokladu(PNS)"),
                        c26 = r.Field<string>("Datum OD"),
                        c27 = r.Field<string>("Datum DO"),
                        c28 = r.Field<string>("Značka"),
                        c29 = r.Field<string>("Sezona"),
                        c30 = r.Field<string>("Výrobní č."),
                        c31 = r.Field<string>("Popis_Rozpis"),
                        c32 = r.Field<string>("Sufix EAN")
                    })
                    .GroupBy(g => new { g.c1, g.c4, g.c5, g.c6, g.c7, g.c8, g.c9, g.c10, g.c11, g.c12, g.c13, g.c14, g.c15, g.c16, g.c17, g.c18, g.c19, g.c20, g.c21, g.c22, g.c23, g.c24, g.c25, g.c26, g.c27, g.c28, g.c29, g.c30, g.c31, g.c32 })
                    .Select(x => new { 
                        col1 = x.Key.c1,
                        col2 = x.Sum(s => double.Parse(s.c2, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
                        col3 = x.Sum(s => double.Parse(s.c3, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
                        col4 = x.Key.c4,
                        col5 = x.Key.c5,
                        col6 = x.Key.c6,
                        col7 = x.Key.c7,
                        col8 = x.Key.c8,
                        col9 = x.Key.c9,
                        col10 = x.Key.c10,
                        col11 = x.Key.c11,
                        col12 = x.Key.c12,
                        col13 = x.Key.c13,
                        col14 = x.Key.c14,
                        col15 = x.Key.c15,
                        col16 = x.Key.c16,
                        col17 = x.Key.c17,
                        col18 = x.Key.c18,
                        col19 = x.Key.c19,
                        col20 = x.Key.c20,
                        col21 = x.Key.c21,
                        col22 = x.Key.c22,
                        col23 = x.Key.c23,
                        col24 = x.Key.c24,
                        col25 = x.Key.c25,
                        col26 = x.Key.c26,
                        col27 = x.Key.c27,
                        col28 = x.Key.c28,
                        col29 = x.Key.c29,
                        col30 = x.Key.c30,
                        col31 = x.Key.c31, 
                        col32 = x.Key.c32  
                    });
```

But this code not Grouping and suming rows...Have you any ideas please?

Example: I have 2 same rows with diferent columns "Množství" and Nákupní cena". From this 2 rows i want to do one row where is SUM "Množství" and Nákupní cena".

Short variant of code:

```
var res = RadkyData.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(r=>new 
                    {
                        c1 = r.Field<string>("ČísloDokladuDodavatele"),
                        c2 = r.Field<string>("Množství"),
                        c3 = r.Field<string>("NákupníCena"),                        
                    })
                    .GroupBy(g => new { g.c1 })
                    .Select(x => new { 
                        col1 = x.Key.c1,
                        col2 = x.Sum(s => double.Parse(s.c2, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
                        col3 = x.Sum(s => double.Parse(s.c3, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
                    });
```

Comment: You need `First()` only on non grouped items, so just do `x.Key.c8`.

Comment: Are you trying to select all rows and to make a SUMM only of those, which have the same values in KódZboží,Ean,Velikost?

Comment: I dont know how...

Comment: Result of my code is only same rows as original...But the rows not summed :(

Comment: I mean, do you want to group by these three columns? Or to make a SUM without grooping? Because in first case you have to group only by these three columns to get a SUM. And you are grouping by all columns. That wount bring you SUM if for instance Date differs.

Comment: Example: I have 2 same rows with diferent "Množství" and Nákupní cena". From this 2 rows i want to do one row where i SUM "Množství" and Nákupní cena".

Comment: Well if content of ALL columns is equal and only "Množství" and Nákupní cena" differs it should work like you wrote it. For testing you may reduce the number of your columns in the second select and look if sum works.

Comment: Like:  `.GroupBy(g => new {g.c7})
                    .Select(x => new { 
                        col1 = x.Sum(s => double.Parse(s.c2, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
                        col2 = x.Sum(s => double.Parse(s.c3, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
                        col3 = x.Key.c7.First()                       
                    });`

Comment: I try this, but result is still bad...

Comment: Please post a short variant of yours

Comment: This is my first 2 rows in datatable:  http://postimg.org/image/67osrzyz5/       http://postimg.org/image/52uqmmci9/

Comment: I mean post the code of a short variant..

Comment: I edited first post and add short variant of code...

Comment: Just looked at your results... it looks good - the first column is unique as it was grouped by it. what results are you awaiting?

Comment: @Julia I awaiting: if i have for example  same rows where are different only columns Množství and Nákupní Cena -> result will one row with summed Množství and Nákupní cena...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hier I created a table:
[image]

Hier is the sql query you are trying to implement with Linq and the results:
[image]

Hier is the Linq code I used to get the SUMs:

```
var result = ctx.Set<RadkyData>()
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.c1, x.c2, x.c3, x.c4, x.c5, x.c6 })
            .Select(x => new
                            {
                                col1 = x.Key.c1,
                                col_Mnozstvi = x.Sum(y => y.Množství),
                                col_NakupniCena = x.Sum(y => y.NákupníCena),
                                col2 = x.Key.c2,
                                col3 = x.Key.c3,
                                col4 = x.Key.c4,
                                col5 = x.Key.c5,
                                col6 = x.Key.c6
                            });
```

Look, all the fields but "Množství" and Nákupní cena" have equal values.

Hier is the result of the Linq - it is the same with the result of an SQL query:
[image]

You wrote:

> I need SUM column "Množství" and column "NákupníCena", where is the columns: KódZboží,Ean,Velikost are the same in rows.

But you are grouping by ALL fields, where the values can differ! You have to group only by those rows where the values are being expected to be the same. These are in your case only "KódZboží", "Ean" and "Velikost". In this case you'll get the right SUM.

Comment: Thanks, but when i try to grouping only on one of the column (Short variant of code) i have same count of rows in result...no grouping on my data..

Comment: And that is right. Try To group ONLY by "KódZboží", "Ean" and "Velikost". Your short variant works fine, but you obviously have no equal data in your "ČísloDokladuDodavatele" filed. So there was no grouping in this case.

Comment: Sorrrrrrryyyyyy :)) It run...i look bad on results all the time!! Thanks for Help :)